# Data type for SQL that preserves trailing zeroes with dynamic number of decimal places

Tags: sql, types, rounding, geospatial

I'm working with latitude/longitude data in SQL that is going to be collected from a wide variety of sources with varying precision.

I'm trying to figure out a data type that will preserve trailing zeros without using `decimal` to set an amount of zeros. 12.345 should be different from 12.34500. Is there a way to do this without simply converting these values to character? That seems to be the obvious solution but I'm trying to get a better idea of the range of options.

Comment: When they’re strings, you could count the trailing zeroes, and then store the precision of each set of coordinates alongside their numerical values. Then you can still store them as numbers but still know their precision.

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the trailing zeroes? Is it because they represent different accuracies/precisions? If that's the case you can store the number and its accuracy as two separate columns.

Comment: Always make sure you take the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) into account

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve zeros after the decimal place -- and distinguish between numbers that are otherwise numerically equal -- then I think you need to use strings:

```
'12.345'
'12.34500'
```